# Setting a style on an individual view does not work

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I'm having trouble setting a theme on individual views in one of my activities.

Setting the theme in the application tag in my manifest works perfectly, as does setting the theme in the activity tags in the manifest.

Regardless of whether I have a theme set in the manifest or not, if I try and set a theme on an individual view:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/userFullNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImageView"
        android:text="Bobby Joe"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" />
```

the view always appears with either the default theme (nothing set in manifest) or the same theme specified in the manifest.

I'm not overriding the Theme.Sherlock.Light theme anywhere in my xml files.  I've tried several different combinations of themes to no avail.  Oh, and I'm obviously using ActionBarSherlock.

**EDIT**

If I create a new style:

```
<style name="SideMenuStyle" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
</style>
```

and use this style in my xml, it still does not display the correct style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `android:theme` xml attribute defined for views. You can use `style` xml attribute instead, but you have to reference a style for the view instead of the whole theme.
Use it like this:

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userFullNameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImageView"
    android:text="Bobby Joe"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    style="@style/MyTextViewStyle" />
```

Note that you can also define a default theme for all instances of `TextView` or any other widget within the scope of a theme. For `TextView` that would mean to define `android:textViewStyle` in the theme:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>
```